# Relationship between analytic continuity and 2-adic convergence of the sum of powers of 2

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, analytic-continuation

Using the 2-adic metric for natural numbers, we have
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n =^2 -1 $$
where $=^2$ is used to denote convergence of the partial sum with respect to the 2-adic metric. On the other hand, in the usual Euclidian metric we have
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty p^n = \frac{1}{1-p}$$
for complex numbers $\left| p \right| < 1$. The right-hand function has a unique analytic continuation to all of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$. Evaluated at $p=2$, this gives the 'relationship'
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n =^{a} -1 $$
where $=^a$ is used to denote the evaluation provided through analytic continuity. What is the reason for this connection between 2-adic convergence of the sum and its evaluation through analytic continuity? Why do they both give $-1$?

Comment: Let's say, they have the same proof, *formally*, but there are convergence issues with $\sum_n2^n$ in the usual metric. The $2$-adic setting enables to speak about its limit, then the formal deduction becomes valid.

Comment: You have one formal series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n X^n\in \Bbb{Q}[[X]]$ which defines two (unrelated) analytic functions on a disk of $\Bbb{Q}_2$ and $\Bbb{C}$. The point is that one of those is equal to a rational function $\in \Bbb{Q}(X)$, thus so are the others. This rational function when evaluated at a rational number (where it doesn't have a pole) gives the same value in $\Bbb{Q}_2$ and $\Bbb{C}$. Finally the rational function defines the analytic (meromorphic) continuation of each analytic functions.

Comment: The ultimate reason for the similarity is the well-known identity $(1-x)\cdot \sum_{i=0}^k x^i = 1-x^{k+1}$ a.k.a. $\sum_{i=0}^k x^i =\dfrac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}$ which holds true as soon as one can write down both sides. And then one can investigate in what cases one has topological structures which allow us to take a limit for $k \to \infty$, here in particular when $x$ is "small". To then see the connection rigorously, follow reuns' comment. Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2934727/96384 for another not-so-mysterious analogy related to the geometric series.

Comment: Thanks for all these comments. But @reuns, why does the function evaluate to the same number in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ and in $\mathbb{C}$, or perhaps equivalently, why does the formal series define the same rational function for each $X$?