# $10$ adic numbers Does infinite equal $-1$

Tags: infinity, p-adic-number-theory

Sorry math newbie here. I saw a video that said $9999$ repeating actually equals $-1$.  This logic helped people understand $10$ adic numbers.

Under this logic doesn't that mean infinity is equal to $-1$?

Comment: The sequence $\{10^n-1\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ goes to infinity in the standard metric on the real line, but in the $10$-adic numbers, $10^n$ goes to zero. This is really the whole point - $g$-adic numbers have a different idea about the size of numbers. In one number system, this sequence goes to infinity, and another it goes to $-1.$ But that doesn't mean $-1$ and $\infty$ are the same, because we are talking about fundamentally different notions of convergence.

Comment: In $10$-adic numbers, in particular, we can have divergent sequences, but there is no

Comment: You can only say that "ordinary" integers $9$, $99$, $999$ etc. "grow" and therefore "tend to infinity" because there is the comparison relation $\le$ between them. For $n$-adics there is _no such comparison_ relation. $99$ is not "bigger" than $99$, $999$ is not "bigger" than $99$ etc.  You therefore cannot extend $n$-adics with $\infty$ (or $-\infty$) the way we do it for integers.

Comment: In fact, I believe you are talking about https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRaq4aYPzCc (brilliant video by Veritasium BTW) - re-watch somewhere around 26:31, where (on the example of $3$-adics) they explain that those numbers _don't belong to a number line_ but actually make up an intricate fractal-like structure.

Comment: Compare the (rightfully) strongly worded answers to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2934305/96384 whose fancier terminology and neat graphs distract from it being based on the same misunderstanding. Apparently we do a bad job in highlighting the simple basic fact: that with respect to different orders/metrics/topologies, one and the same sequence can have different limits.

Comment: `The sequence {10n−1}∞n=1
 goes to infinity in the standard metric on the real line, but in the 10
-adic numbers, 10n
 goes to zero.`
Does this mean that -999999 is == 1 in ten-adics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"actually equals". N.B. I use $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N9\cdot10^n$ as a precise interpretation of "$99999\cdots$ repeating". Notice $\sum_{n=0}^N9\cdot10^n=\underset{N+1\text{ times }}{\underbrace{99999\cdots999}}$.

$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N9\cdot 10^n=-1$ in the $10$-adics, sure. And $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N9\cdot10^n=+\infty$ in the extended real numbers. We've taken limits in different spaces and arrived at different answers.

Nowhere in the above is there any logical link which deduces $+\infty=-1$ as an equality of extended reals; it is false. There are just different rules at play.

Comment: If anything, the $10$-adic $$...99999 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 9 \cdot 10^n = -1$$ is the analogue of the real $$0.99999... = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 9 \cdot 10^{\color{red}{-}n} =1$$ (which also invites all kinds of misunderstandings by people who have never played with epsilons).

Comment: Sorry for clarification 99999 repeating forever is the quivalent of inifinity no?

Comment: @johnny5 The point of my answer is that: (a) "$999999$ repeating forever" is, on its own, meaningless and (b) if you choose a meaning*ful* model of this expression, in the limit $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N9\cdot 10^n$, then its value (if it has one at all) completely depends on what the space is. $\infty$ is not a number so, you should be really careful in saying "... the equivalent of infinity". You get $+\infty$ if you work in the extended reals, but you don't if you work in the $10$-adics.

Comment: sorry i should be more clear on why im still confused. What does that equation mean in context, can this be explained in laments terms.  I think what I'm seeing is that.
That real number scale goes to infinity, while the adics number scale goes to 0, or something?

Comment: @johnny5 "Goes to"? You need to accept the idea that not all sets/spaces look like a number line. If anything, it has been said that $n$-adic spaces have a fractal appearance (as a purely intuitive image). All this means is that, say, $99999$ is quite close to $-1$ in the $10$-adics, but in the (extended) real numbers, it is very far away. Different spaces have different topologies, different "neighbourhoods", different ways of "measuring closeness".