# are p-adic values infinite if using a limit?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I watched a [Veritasium video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRaq4aYPzCc&t=150s) about p-adic numbers.

In [2:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRaq4aYPzCc&t=150s) they take the 10-adic number `...857142857143`, they multiply it by 7 and it happens that this number is designed in a way that all products except the first one result in a number ending in 0 and carrying some value.

Since the 10-adic number has infinite digits, this results in a 1 with infinite zeros on the left, so in the video they then claim that this equals 1, and therefore this 10-adic number represents the number 1/7

```
...857142857143
   x          7
   ____________
...000000000001
```

Saying that the result is 1 makes some kind of logic (we have a non ending amount of zeros on the left, so what else could it be?)

However there's always a non-zero carry that will never disappear that we just completely discarded without any more explanation.

Here is my logic:

Let's start with a finite multiplications using the first 4 digits of the previous example:

```
  7143
  x  7
 _____
 50001
```

The result is 50001

We can write this result as a sum of two terms: the 1 that we obtain if we discard the last carry, and the carry itself, which will be some value k multiplied by 10^i  where i is the index at which the carry finally settles (in this case 4)

```
50001 = 5*10^4 + 1
```

Now if instead of a finite 4 digit number we have a number with infinite numbers, we just take the limit when i tends to infinity and we calculate the result.

Here k represents the carry value, which we know it is a non-zero integer in the range [1..9]

$$\lim_{i\to\infty} k\cdot10^i + 1$$

The result of this sum (that does take in account the carry and doesn't magically discard it as they do in the video) is, as expected, infinite, meaning that the number ...857142857143 represents an infinite value.

Is there any flaw in my logic of using a limit to take in account the value of the carry, and therefore obtaining an infinite value instead of a value of 1?

I understand that such number could never be constructed, so their infinite value could never be achieved.
But the same applies to functions that converge to a value, we know that they will never reach that value but we have tools like limits to compute what that value is.

I know I must be wrong, since p-adic numbers is an field of mathematics, and the fact that they represent finite numbers is accepted, I just want to see what's wrong with the limit approach that sets its value to infinite.

Comment: The number $0.\overline{142857}$ has an infinite number of digits after the decimal point.  Would you say that $0.\overline{142857}$ represents an infinite value?

Comment: no, because in this case each digit's contribution gets smaller and smaller.  I'm aware that series of infinite decreasing numbers can converge to a finite number and I understand them. But in p-adic numbers each digit adds an increasingly bigger value.

Comment: That series gets closer and closer to $1$, with the $10$-adic metric

Comment: But in a $p$-adic absolute value, the digits farther to the *left* contribute less and less.

Comment: In decimal numbers, each new digit moving ***to the right*** is smaller and smaller. But in $p$-adic numbers, each new digit moving ***to the left*** is smaller and smaller.

Comment: If we allow numbers on the left behave differently depending if we have finite or infinite amounts of them, then why not doing the same with irrational numbers? I can declare that in irrational numbers the first decimal contributes the least to the result. But we know this is not true. It sounds like just changing rules for convenience. I know there's a good reason, I just fail to see how this matches reality. Using a limit as I did in the question the result is infinite, and the approach makes sense. So my question is what part of this approach is wrong.

Comment: The number $\ldots 857142857143$ *is* a rational number in the $10$-adic system.  It is $1/7$ (which is what the argument from the video shows).  It is also worth noting that, in the $10$-adic system, $|10^j|_{10} = 10^{-j}$.  So the terms that you are adding get smaller and smaller and smaller (not bigger).  It is a different notion of size.

Comment: With respect to "matching" reality, (1) who cares?  we often change our assumptions just to see what is happening, and (2) who's to say that this doesn't match reality, somewhere?  The real numbers, with respect to the usual absolute value, have the property that if $N$ is any positive real number, no matter how large, and $\varepsilon$ is any positive real number, no matter how small, there exists some integer $n$ such that $n\varepsilon > N$.  This is called the *Archimedean property*.  The $p$-adic numbers do not have this property.

Comment: In the $p$-adic numbers, if you add two numbers together, the result cannot be larger than either of the two numbers you started with.  Now, think about a digital camera sensor.  The sensor (for an individual pixel) won't trigger if just one photon hits it.  In order to trigger, a certain number of photons need to hit the sensor in a short period of time.  It will never trigger if it gets hit by one photon, then another, then another.  But if, say, 50 photons arrive all at once, it *will* trigger.  This has kind of a non-Archimedean, p-adic-y feel to it.

Comment: Which is not to say that $p$-adic number are the right kind of thing to model a camera sensor, but it suggests that non-Archimedean phenomena exist, and it can be argued that the $p$-adic numbers are the simplest kind of non-Archimedean thing to wrap your head around.

Comment: Besides, take care of the fact that $10$ isn't a prime number : 10-adic numbers have poorer properties than for example 11-adic numbers.

Comment: sorry but none of this answers my question. I have an approach using a limit to calculate a value of a 10-adic number and my question is about what assumption is wrong in using a limit to calculate the value.

Comment: In the $10$-adic absolute value (in so much as there is a $10$-adic absolute value), $5000$ is much smaller than $1$.  Digits farther to the left are *small*.  So in your limit computation, the additional terms are not adding anything of significance.

Comment: The most basic answer is that $\lim_{t\to\infty} 10^t=0$ in $10$-adic numbers, so $\lim_{t\to\infty} k\cdot 10^t+1=1$. Limits are always calculated with respect to certain _metric_ (or, more widely, _topology_) and the metric on $10$-adic numbers is given by _$10$-adic norm_, which is (if I am not mistaken) $|x|_{10}=\begin{cases}10^{-k}&x\ne 0,x\text{ ends with }k\text{ zeros }\\0&x=0\end{cases}$.

Comment: You may want to study the concepts of [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Convergence) and [normed space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space) for somewhat more detailed understanding of limits.

Comment: @StinkingBishop That is basically correct, though it only applies to the absolute value of an integer.  More generally, represent a number by a power sum/series: $$x = \sum_{j=-n}^{\infty} d_j 10^{j}. $$  Then the $10$-adic absolute value of $x$ is $$|x|_{10} = 10^{n}.$$

Comment: And, for the record, we are *really* talking about [valuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra)) and [absolute values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value_(algebra)).  The distinction between an absolute value and a norm is subtle, but it exists.

Comment: The flaw is in the sentence "The result of this sum (that does take in account the carry and doesn't magically discard it as they do in the video) is, as expected, infinite" -- no, with respect to the $10$-value, the "result" (i..e limit) of this is not infinite. (If you consider that sequence with respect to the usual absolute value, it goes to infinity. The same sequence can go to different limits when considered with respect to different metrics.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$10$ adic numbers Does infinite equal $-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720642/10-adic-numbers-does-infinite-equal-1)

Comment: To summarize - the flaw in your logic is that you are treating the 10-adics as some extension of the Real numbers, but that is not correct. Addition and multiplication work the same way. But the *topology* of the 10-adics - how limits work - is  different. In some ways (but not all ways), you can consider the topology of 10-adics to be the "reverse" of that of the Reals. In the reals, the more leading $0$s a number has, the smaller it is, while in the 10-adics, the more trailing $0$s a number has, the smaller it is.